# How would you judge the performance of an LSTM for time series predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, accuracy, lstm

For an LSTM model for forecasting time series, what metrics or tests would you use to evaluate its performance (i.e loss, RMSE, accuracy etc). I'm slightly confused because I read that time series forecasting is considered a regression problem so accuracy doesn't apply but I have also seen many time series models use accuracy as a metric. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not an expert for time series data, but I guess it totally depends on what you are prediciting. When you try to forecast the probability of rain measured as % you could use metrics like loss mse rmse. If you instead on every day assign a label (sunny, rain, ...) which you try to forecast the labels of previous days you stick to classification metrics like accuracy or kappa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time series prediction is a regression problem and you should consult to regression error metrics. However, you can make a classification based on time series. For example, you might need to decide a person's health status considering some physiological recordings. Then, your problem turns into a classification task where you can use classification metrics such as accuracy. I presume this is the source of your confusion

There are multiple metrics for quantifying time series prediction models. Some of them:

- Mean Absolute Error:  $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|y_i-y_i'|$
- Mean Squared Error:  $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-y_i')^2$
- Mean Percentage Absolute Error : $(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}|\frac{y_i-y_i'}{y_i}|)$x$100$

where $y,y'$ and $N$ are observed time samples, predicted time samples and total number of time samples used for error calculation, respectively. The procedure is straightforward: using previous time samples, you predict following $N$ time samples and calculate error based on these predicted samples.

Although these all are widely used, percentage error is a good starting point since it is not affected by the data scaling and therefore, easier to interpret.

Comment: Thank you so much, it make sense now!